# Why isn't the stroke color changing?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the color to change for each square drawn.
Maybe it has something to do with rgb? But im really new to this so I don't really know haha.

Have no idea what else to try.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IDK</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color:rgb(30, 30, 30);
        color:White;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>IDK</h2>
    <canvas id="minCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("minCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var side=600;
      var x=0;
      var y=0;
      var a = 255;
      var b = 255;
      var c = 255;
      while (side>0) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(a,b,c)";
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, side, side);
        //ctx.stroke();
        a-=50;
        b-=10;
        c-=30;
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
        side-=10;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The variable values are not automagically resolved from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly insert the variables into the rgb string:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+a+","+b+","+c+")"
```

You can also use template strings if supported:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(${a},${b},${c})`
```

```js
      var canvas = document.getElementById("minCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var side=600;
      var x=0;
      var y=0;
      var a = 255;
      var b = 255;
      var c = 255;
      while (side>0) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+a+","+b+","+c+")";
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, side, side);
        //ctx.stroke();
        a-=50;
        b-=10;
        c-=30;
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
        side-=10;
      }
```

```css
      body {
        background-color:rgb(30, 30, 30);
        color:White;
      }
```

```html
    <h2>IDK</h2>
    <canvas id="minCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```